# can graph api be used to generate database of public events of some pages without integrating facebook login in my app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create a small updatable database of the public events created by few selected FB pages (of which I'm admin of none), I think FB's graph API can do the job well, but I'm not willing to create an FB login in my app, I just need to access public events maybe twice daily and create a database (from my personal account) which will then be used in my app. Is there any way to do this?

I've tried fetching data from graph API explorer but it pops up an error saying my app needs to be reviewed first by FB before I get access to public events

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the events of a Page:

> This is a restricted edge. You cannot request access at this time.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events/